# How to Find a Control on a Master page from a User Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, master-pages

I am trying to change the CSS attributes of a DIV on a Master Page from a User Control but I haven't succeeded so far. The Codes are as follows:

MasterPage

```
 .....
 <div class="BGfixed" id="masterpageBody" runat="server"></div>
 .....
```

Content Page

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/main.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="background.aspx.cs" Inherits="bardaba.Members.background" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="editingPages" Src="~/UserControls/editingPages.ascx" %>
 ....
 <uc:editingPages id="editingPages1" runat="server" />
```

User Control - Code Behind

```
 HtmlGenericControl background_image = (HtmlGenericControl)Master.FindControl("masterpageBody");
            background_image.Attributes.Add("style", "background-image:url(/Members/images/BG/" + imgBG_user + ")");
```

Since the Master Page doesn't exist in the context of the User Control then I'm getting an error. How can I refer to the Master Page from the User Control other than Master.FindControl...?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `this.Page.Master`:

```
HtmlGenericControl background_image = (HtmlGenericControl)Page.Master.FindControl("masterpageBody");
background_image.Attributes.Add("style", "background-image:url(/Members/images/BG/" + imgBG_user + ")");
```

Comment: Actually it was me. Humayun just edited the question :D

Comment: I was just kidding. REALLY there is no need to tank anybody. We are here to help each other :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58545/discussion-between-gloria-and-alireza).